# E-mail Template for Hiding and Display Images & Text

Tags: html, css, email

Bit of an amateur when it comes to coding ... especially when it comes to e-mail templates. I'm having a hard time getting G-mail to actually hide and display things correctly. I have searched on here and find some answers that I thought would help, but it doesn't seem to fit well in my code. Not worried about the code when being forwarded as of now.

Here is the portion of code with the images specifically. Would love some eyes on it, and some help as well. Everything is in one table, and works fine in a normal browser ... just looking for help in G-mail specifically.

**CSS:**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {

  .mobilechart {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

  .desktopchart {
    display: none !important;
  }
```

**HTML:**

```
<tr>
  <td style="background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:right;" >
    <div class="desktopchart">
      <img src="https://cdn.maropost.com/pro/uploads/account_415/77640/TC-Email_Template_DESKTOPCHART.jpg" style="width:100%;margin-top:auto;margin-bottom:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;" >
    </div>
    <div class="mobilechart">
      <img src="https://cdn.maropost.com/pro/uploads/account_415/77641/TC-Email_Template_MOBILECHART.jpg" style="width:100%;margin-top:auto;margin-bottom:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;" >
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Newsletter can't hide responsive content on gmail and when I try to forward the e-mail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37182935/newsletter-cant-hide-responsive-content-on-gmail-and-when-i-try-to-forward-the)

Answer (score 1):

Reposting my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37182935/):

The bad news here is that, unfortunately, GMail does not yet support media queries nor does it support the `display`, `overflow` or `visibility` properties.

See [Campaign Monitor's CSS Support Guide for Email Clients](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) for more information.

Other than rewriting your newsletter to be completely fluid, rather than trying to make it responsive, I'm afraid there's no real solution to be had here.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid of that ... this hurts my heart.