# Overriding inliner code for responsive email template

Tags: html, css, email

I am coding a responsive email template using media queries and I have a specific issue.

I am using MailChimps guidelines and therefore I got into using their **[CSS Inliner](http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/)** , but I find an issue where the inlined css somehow overrides and breaks my previously working CSS above in the styles.

So for example here is what I am talking about, here is my not inlined code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        #desktop {display: block;}
        #mobi {display: none !important;}

        @media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
            #desktop {display: none !important}
            #mobi {display: block !important}
        }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="bodyTable">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="emailContainer">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top" id="desktop">
                            This is where my content goes.
                        </td>
                        <td align="center" valign="top" id="mobi">
                            This is where my content goes.
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

This is just for reference, this is not my actual code, but I hope You get the point.

So my problem with this is, after I use the CSS Inliner from MailChimp, I get this:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        #desktop {display: block;}
        #mobi {display: none !important;}

        @media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
            #desktop {display: none !important}
            #mobi {display: block !important}
        }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="bodyTable">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="emailContainer">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top" id="desktop" style="display: block;">
                            This is where my content goes.
                        </td>
                        <td align="center" valign="top" id="mobi" style="display: none !important;">
                            This is where my content goes.
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

And after I send test emails, in the mail clients, most importantly Gmail, everything is wrong, either both of the objects show or the #mobi one is hidden on mobile and vice versa.The !important statement in my upper css in the style section is due to the fact that the #mobi object will always be visible in Gmail unless it has an !important for the display:none property.

I tried deleting the inlined important statements but nothing worked so far. What is the problem here and how can I bypass it?

Answer (score 1):

According to the rules of [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity):

> Inline styles added to an element (e.g., style="font-weight:bold") always overwrite any styles in external stylesheets and thus can be thought of as having the highest specificity.

You could use `!important` in your stylesheet to increase the specificity of the relevant styles, forcing them to override the inline styles. However, it should be [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37184393/4768433) that GMail, among other clients, does not support media queries nor the `display` property.

Comment: Using display: none !important hides content from GMail. But I am still not completely sure that it does not support media queries since it works with some of the code inside them.